# How to save user data in a PyQt application

Tags: linux, qt5, pyqt5

I am making an application for Linux in which user will sign in to his google account then a folder will be created in home folder and all the files that user will create in that folder will be synchronized to cloud(google drive).

Every time when user will connect to the internet, synchronization will be started. So for synchronization, I need user's detail that user will fill after installing the application. I am confused that, How can I store user data. Should I use a database or can I store it in files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save all the login credentials into a .csv or .txt file pretty easily, see [here](https://pastebin.com/46mWQps6) for an example.

```
LoginCreds = [pass,login,so on, so forth]
i=0
  for item in LoginCreds:
  if(i == 0):
    i+=1
    open("FILELOCATION",w).write("")#Overwrite any file w/ same name if needed
  open("FILELOCATION","a").write(item)#actually write stuff to the file
```

You can then pull the data from the txt in the necessary order.

With all that said, there is a major problem with all that. Security. You'd have to encode that data or someone could steal your or someone else's password.

I would suggest saving only some of the information needed to log in (like their email, but not the password). That way there is no need to encode the files, which will make your program faster(no decrypting and re-encrypting passwords and whatnot), but the user will have to login to the application every time, which isn't too bad...